# Proving a topological space is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I am working on a problem where the topological space is completely described. I know that for two elements of the topological space their singleton sets are closed. Because this is the case, I am thinking that there is no way for me to be able to come up with a continuous function that forms a path between the two elements. Is that correct?

Comment: Singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, yet it is path-connected.

Comment: For my example, the topological space is finite. I know that $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are closed and want to find a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow S$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$. My question is whether it's possible to break $[0,1]$ up into two closed intervals so that the pre-image of our closed sets are both closed

Comment: The reason I'm concerned about the fact that both are closed because if only one was it would be easy to break up the interval; though I don't see how to do so in this case or in the case where both are open in the topological space

Comment: Theorem : a finite space is connected iff its is path-connected.

Comment: Does that mean this isn't connected at all?

Comment: Give a complete description of your example if you want confirmation...

Comment: I think I actually figured it out.. I came up with the idea to have the function be defined as $f(0)=a, \quad f((0,1))=c, \quad f(1)=b$. That way the inverse images of $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are closed while still covering the whole interval $[0,1]$ (also $\{c\}$ is open which is why I think this works)

Comment: Please let me know if that appears to be wrong though

Comment: In your example (provided $c\ne a$ and $c\ne b$) the inverse images of $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ cover only a set $\{0,1\}$, but not the interval $[0,1]$.